# How to hide Qt widget application menu bar?

Tags: c++, qt, menu, widget, menubar

By default when creating a new Qt Widget project using Qt Creator. There's a menu bar, and it is shown always even without any menus, sub menus or actions. I don't want to delete this menu bar in designer view, just want to hide it only. Any solution?

Comment: This is incorrect. QWidget and QDialog do not show any menus. Only QMainWindow have a menu.

Comment: i meant Qt Widget application, not the QtWidget class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
ui->menuBar->hide(); // hide menubar
ui->menuBar->show(); // in case you want to restore it
```

in your mainwindow class if you want to hide it in the runtime.

Otherwise, you don't have to create a project with mainwindow.ui everytime. As you start a new project, there's an option in **[Details]->[Base class]** which allows you to choose the base class (template form) as mainwindow, dialog or widget.